# Cannot run jobs in asynchronous in laravel queue

Tags: php, laravel, asynchronous, laravel-queue

I'm want to run some tasks asynchronously in php 5.5 and laravel. I've googled and found out that the laravel queue can do such thing. I found this link for help : https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queues.
I've installed the dependencies :

Amazon SQS: aws/aws-sdk-php ~3.0

Beanstalkd: pda/pheanstalk ~3.0

IronMQ: iron-io/iron_mq ~2.0|~4.0

Redis: predis/predis ~1.0

and I've added the queue tables in laravel.Here is my Job class

```
class SearchFromSource extends Job implements SelfHandling{
    use InteractsWithQueue, SerializesModels;
    private $provider;
    private $query;
    private $pageToken;
    private $parameters;
    private $needDetails;

    public function __construct()
    {
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        sleep(5);
    }
}
```

and here is where I dispatch the job:

```
class SearchController extends Controller{
     ...
     public function prepareResults($query, $page, $ip){
        $job = (new SearchFromSource($curVideoProvider,$this->query,$curVideoProvider->getDefaultParameters(),$curPageToken,$curVideoProvider->needDetails()))->onQueue("q1");
        $this->dispatch($job);
        $job2 = (new SearchFromSource($curVideoProvider,$this->query,$curVideoProvider->getDefaultParameters(),$curPageToken,$curVideoProvider->needDetails()))->onQueue("q2");
        $this->dispatch($job2);
    }

}
```

The problem is that the laravel doesn't run the jobs asynchronous. What is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First you must define a `QUEUE_DRIVER` (sync,redis,beanstalk etc) in you .env file
2. Then you must have a a queue listener running  you run `php artisan queue:listen` inside you project directory
3. Your job  should Implement shouldQUeue interface

Comment: I still doesn't work. when I run php artisan queue:listen and dispatch the job it shows nothing in terminal

Comment: witch queue driver do you use ?

Comment: I used sync, database and redis but it makes no diffrence

Comment: you should also implement Should queue

Comment: you should also implement Should queue?? What mean??